# Ext js 5-TypeError: Ext.application is not a function

Tags: javascript, extjs5

app.js file contains :

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'myapp',
  launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      width: 200,
      height: 150,
      bodyPadding: 5,
      title: 'Hello World',
      html: 'Hello <b>World</b>...'
    });
  }
});
```

but i open file app.js i have "TypeError: Ext.application is not a function".

I searh same error on internet, Wrap the call to Ext.application inside an Ext.onReady block. is not working for me.

how can i pass this error please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my fault. i dont't create the jsp files right on my project. It is working now true.

Answer (score 0):

The script files are probably being downloaded in parallel, and the ExtJs one is very large. Try attaching the Ext.application inside a function bound to the window's `onload` event.